# Upgrade Rails 3.2 to 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to update an app using Rails `3.2` to `4.0` for a first step. Having issues because of `railties`. Every time I run `bundle update rails` it throws this error

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
In Gemfile:
railties (~> 3.2.0) ruby

railties (~> 3.2.0) ruby

railties (>= 3.1) ruby

railties (~> 3.1) ruby

railties (< 5.0, >= 3.0) ruby

railties (>= 3.1.0) ruby

railties (< 5.0.0, >= 3.0.0) ruby

railties (>= 3.1) ruby

mercury-rails (>= 0) ruby depends on
  railties (~> 3.2) ruby

railties (>= 3.2.16) ruby

railties (< 4.1, >= 3.1) ruby

railties (>= 3.0) ruby

railties (>= 3.0.0) ruby

railties (< 5.0, >= 3.2) ruby

rails (= 4.0.3) ruby depends on
  railties (= 4.0.3) ruby
```

I have rails 4.0.0 installed `rails (4.2.4, 4.0.3, 4.0.1, 4.0.0, 3.2.20)`

My gem file looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.6'

gem 'rails', '4.0.3'
```

Comment: Mercury rails is dependent on rails 3.2, and doesn't seem to have had a commit since late 2013 so looks like you'll need to upgrade that yourself or switch to something else.  I'm guessing you have some other gems that need updating due to similar issues too.

Comment: @japed this did get the mercury-rails message to go away but still getting the railties issue.

Comment: I assume some of your other gems have issues too, I'd comment them all out, and readd them one by one to find the ones causing the dependency mismatch errors, then update them as appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have problem with this:

Try deleting `Gemfile.lock` and then run:

```
bundle install
```

If this fails, remove version numbers from the `Gemfile`. And, then try again.

Comment: Deleting the `Gemfile.lock` won't help, and at least mercury rails has the version numbers specified in the gem.

Comment: After removing / updating a bunch of version numbers still got the issue. Since I was on a branch I decided to just delete the .lock file and bundle install. finally got everything to install